# Overlapped background <img> - text and background-color inconsistency

Tags: css, background-image

```css
.background {
width: 50%;
height: 10rem;
overflow:hidden;
}

.mysection {
background-color: red;
position:relative;
margin-top:-4rem;
}

.mysection h1 {
color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/NGC_4414_%28NASA-med%29.jpg/1024px-NGC_4414_%28NASA-med%29.jpg">
</div>

<section class="mysection">
  <h1> section text </h1>
</section>
```

I was following along a React tutorial when I noticed a strange behavior in the code snippet above (simplified from the full code).

When `position:relative` is removed from `.mysection`, the `<h1>` remains above the `<img>`, but the `background-color` of `.mysection` goes behind the `<img>`.

Why does removing `position:relative` cause this? Shouldn't `<h1>` get moved along with `.mysection`?